# SwiftUI Picker view without label

Tags: ios, swiftui

EDIT: I tried using the WheelPickerStyle outside of the form, however what I want is the same idea, the actual options instead of the label, but as a list. Just like in my example with the Form, it's perfect except it has a label I have to click to get there.

I have an app which has a button that redirects me to another view like this:

```
Button(action: {
                        self.isAddDrinkView.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .padding(.bottom, 50.0)
                    }
```

Now, this other view is supposed to be a list from where you could pick one, and only one, element.

I tried doing it like this:

```
struct AddDrinkView: View {
    @ObservedObject var context: Context
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
            Picker(selection: $context.selectedItems, label: Text("Select a drink"), content: {
                ForEach(context.items){
                    Text("\($0)")
                }
            }).pickerStyle(DefaultPickerStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Select a Drink")
            }.labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

However, my problem is that this shows me a view with a picker and a hidden label. I don't want this label at all, I'd prefer the picker options to show immediately when I enter this view, without having to click on a label.

How can I achieve this? this is for ios 13+
Another option if possible was if I could somehow make the first button be the trigger for the picker options view, but I still don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This a way `Form` presents default styled picker. Try to use instead `WheelPickerStyle`

```
Picker(selection: $context.selectedItems, label: Text("Select a drink"), content: {
    ForEach(context.items){
        Text("\($0)")
    }
}).pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())      // << here !!
```

Comment: I tried using the WheelPickerStyle outside of the form, however what I want is the same idea, the actual options instead of the label, but as a list. Just like in my example with the Form, it's perfect except it has a label I have to click to get there.

Comment: Do I have to make a list and somehow create logic to allow you to pick one?

Comment: As variant, why not?

Comment: I just thought the idea is something so basic. I have an image button that I click and then a list of options appears where I can choose one. Can’t I do that without custom logic on swiftui by default?

Comment: Well as it sounds "click and then a list of options" ... not a "form with picker to select options" )) so List allows single selection... go ahead.

Comment: See for example of List with selection https://stackoverflow.com/a/61838512/12299030 (it is actually wider then you need, but for demo is ok).

Comment: Thank you. I did that and it worked exactly like I wanted it!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the label property when initialising to `EmptyView()`.

```swift
Picker(selection: $context.selectedItems, label: EmptyView()) {
    ForEach(colors, id: \.self) {
        Text($0)
    }
}
```

If you were to use an empty `Text` for the `label` property, it would show an empty bar, at least when using `pickerStyle(.inline)`. If you use `EmptyView`, there is no empty bar and you are able to display a picker without a label.

Answer (score -1):

You Can use Menu as Label

```
  Menu("Drop Your Label Here") {
                    Picker("Please choose a color", selection: $selectedColor)
                    {
                        ForEach(colors, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                //.foregroundColor(Color.init("Red"))
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            }.frame(width: 300, height: 60)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).